# add two sql queries

Tags: php, mysql

How do I add two sql queries and result the final value of the second column ?

Example?

TABLE ONE

```
colum 1 | colum 2

10      |   5
```

RESULT:

TABLE ONE

```
colum 1 | colum 2

0       |   15
```

Query:

```
select colum 1 + colum 2 from TABLE ONE
```

Comment: besides the fact that these aren't valid column/table names, you have the right idea. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You would do a JOIN query and perform the math.

Comment: Why do you want the 0?

Comment: `select '0', colum 1 + colum 2 from TABLE ONE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to update the rows with the squashed values?

```
UPDATE Table1 t1 SET t1.column2 = t1.column1 + t1.colum2, t1.column1 = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you Nicolas , was exactly what I wanted to do.